# sidebar hierarchical menu category & custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, menus

I'm working on a site with courses. I've created a custom post type "Course" and need to create a sidebar menu with the list of courses under the active category and then with anchor links to the custom fields within the course.

The easiest way to see what I'm trying to achieve is to have a look at the mock up the designer created here: http://sharebucketapp.com/mMTk2YjRhNjNlMTAyNTk

[image]

I'm at a complete loss as to how to go about this. I'm proficient in php but Wordpress is new to me and I'm having difficulty getting my head around it.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Rob.

Answer (score 0):

So you are saying that you have a set amount of courses and depending on which page they are on (a certain course), they will see a unique sidebar with links relevant to that course? How many courses are there?

Comment: The main course categories are set (audio, film, games, animation) but the courses are dynamic, as in they can add or remove courses in the backend. If the category is Audio (as is the case in the image), the courses in Audio are shown in the tree, and if one of the courses is selected the custom field headings are shown with anchor links to the section of the page. I've managed to (crudely) find and display the anchor links using get_custom_field() but can't figure out the tree structure. I could easily figure this out in Codeigniter/Laravel etc. but Wordpress hacking is new to me. Thanks.